# Edit a page/post DB data?

Tags: plugins, database, post-editor

Hello fellow Wordpress users. I purchased a theme, and it has some content blocks ready to use. I enjoy the simplicity of this, but I cannot fine-tune the details of these blocks.

I eventually found the low-level data for the page in the database (in the wp_posts table) and edited that. (This is the data you see when comparing revisions of a page in the admin dashboard.)

So my question is this: **Is there a plugin or a built-in way to directly edit the database data for a page (and perhaps its revisions)?** I've done some searching, but haven't come up with a solution yet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to directly edit the database data for a page or its revisions in WordPress. However, you can achieve this by using a plugin such as **WP-DB Manager**, which provides a user-friendly interface for managing and editing your WordPress database. This plugin allows you to directly edit the database data for a page and its revisions, as well as perform other database management tasks like backing up, restoring, and optimizing your database.